# Why is basic_string::swap not noexcept?

Tags: c++, c++11

I just found out that the two swap functions for basic_string (member function and function in namespace std) are not declared with *noexcept* - neither in the standard library of GCC-4.8 nor in the most recent C++ draft N3690.

On the other hand, the move constructor as well as the move assignment operator are declared with *noexcept*. That shows that is should be possible to provide *noexcept* swap functions.

**Question:** What's the reason for not having the swap functions declared with *noexcept*?

**Update:** The problem is that I want to use a template function within my own swap functions, that uses static_assert to check that the swap is actually *noexcept*, e.g.:

```
struct foo {
    bar_t bar;
    baz_t baz;
    void swap(foo& rhs) noexcept {
        swap_noexcept(bar, rhs.bar);
        swap_noexcept(baz, rhs.baz);
    }
};
```

However, that works only if the swap functions are declared with *noexcept*, and that's not the case for `basic_string`.

Comment: Maybe it is just an oversight. The specification for `basic_string<>::swap` does state _Throws: Nothing._

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Paragraph 21.4.6.8 of the C++11 Standard specifies:

> 21.4.6.8 `basic_string::swap` [string::swap]
>
> ```
> void swap(basic_string& s);
> ```
>
> 1 *Postcondition*: *this contains the same sequence of characters that was in s, s contains the same
>   sequence of characters that was in *this.
>
> 2 ***Throws*: Nothing**.
>
> 3 *Complexity*: constant time.

Therefore, one must conclude the absence of `noexcept` is an oversight.

Another clue is given by paragraph 21.4.6.3 on the `assign()` member function:

> ```
> basic_string& assign(basic_string&& str) noexcept;
> ```
>
> *Effects*: The function replaces the string controlled by `*this` with a string of length `str.size()` whose
>   elements are a copy of the string controlled by `str`. [ **Note: A valid implementation is `swap(str)`**. —
>   end note ]
>
> 3 *Returns*: `*this.`

If `swap(str)` is supposed to be a valid implementation for `assign()`, and `assign()` is marked as unconditionally `noexcept`, then it makes sense to assume `swap()` to be `noexcept` as well.

Comment: "Throws: Nothing" isn't the same as noexcept in the current standard. If a function has preconditions, and a call violates those preconditions, that causes undefined behavior, for which the implementation is allowed to throw an exception. If the precondition-ful function were declared noexcept, that exception would result in terminate() instead of propagating.

However, string::swap doesn't list any preconditions, meaning that this does look like a mistake. We'd need to check the allocators' propagate-on-swap rules to be sure.

Comment: I have added some background information to the question. The problem is, that without _noexcept_ the static_assert check in my function template fails. Of course there is a simple workaround: I can overload the function template for basic_string. But I am interested in the reason for the non-existent _noexcept_.

Comment: @Jeffrey Yasskin Isn't it allowed by the specification, when undefined behaviour occurs, for a `noexcept` function to throw an exception without calling `std::terminate()`?